# Python script in 4 unexpected Linux instances

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, process

I have python script running on startup by shell script which just makes sure to run it again if it exits with error. There is no problem there, it's been working for long time.

I have made minor updates to script.py (adding libary and calling it every 20 minutes) and after reboot I see 4 script.py processes in *htop* pid 991, 1034, 1035, 1036. but according to log file, script is run only one time. I'm not using sub-processes or threading.

I can see in *Tree* view that higher number processes are child of 991, but why did that happen and can it cause problems?

Comment: Share your file please.

Comment: Show the shell script.